# How can i log out from my own created gsp view with spring security installed in grails app?

Tags: grails, spring-security, logout

I have installed spring security plug in to grails project.i have made my default action as auth. and when i login i get gsp view created by me.now how can i log out from there..

Thanks,
LAxmi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a link to `/logout` - `LogoutController` will log you out.

For example: `<g:link controller='logout'>Logout</g:link>`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Trying it with Spring Security Plugin 2.0-RC2 and the logout controller now only accepts POST calls.

Comment: It's configurable though - see `logout.postOnly` at http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/urlProperties.html

Comment: That link 404s.  I think it is now http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/urlProperties.html But not sure that is helping me anyway.

Answer (score 6):

After changes in Spring Security Plugin 2.0-XX, you can use a POST request using the remoteLink tag like in the following snippet:

```
<g:remoteLink class="logout" controller="logout" method="post" asynchronous="false" onSuccess="location.reload()">Logout</g:remoteLink>
```

You can customize asynchronous attribute or onSuccess event handler to adapt your usage case.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a link to logout, first you must disable de logout.postOnly property as described in https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.2.x/index.html#configGroovy

in your application.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
```

then just call it as a link in any html tag

```
<a href="/logoff">Salir</a>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is the right answer if server returns error 405. Thanks, it's working perfect in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Add in Config 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false

uses
`<g:link controller='logout'>Logout</g:link>`

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with a form too:

```
<g:form controller="logout">                        
    <g:submitButton name="logout" value="Logout" />
</g:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a logout link to url: /logout

Comment: When i do this its directing me to page with url as **http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_logout** which is blank

Answer (score 0):

As other users mentioned that you have to send the request as `POST` request. Another way to do that in an elegant way using a hidden form and JavaScript to submit it.

```
//jQuery 
 $(function(){
     $('#logout-btn').on('click',function () {
         $('.logout-form').submit()
        })
    })
```

Your GSP should have a hidden form and an anchor.

```
 //GSP
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="logout-btn">Logout</a>
<g:form class="form-inline d-none logout-form" controller="logout"></g:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To logout from application, you need to call the `LogoutController` like:

```
<g:link controller="logout" action="index">Exit</g:link>
```

---

By default, the action `index` of `LogoutController` only accept 'POST' method.

You need to build a form to call it or set the next property in the `application.yml`:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
```

---

If you want to keep that option with its default value, this is how should the form look like:

```
<g:form controller="logout" action="index" method="POST">
    <g:submitButton name="Exit"/>
</g:form>
```

---

**INFO:** action key is not needed (optional), specifying only the controller will get you to the index action.